# How to do a line break after an itemize?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

The question is in the title.

I've

```
\begin{itemize} \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}       
\item item1 ...
\item item2 ....
\end{itemize}                                               

New paragraph etc......
```

I want in the result to have a blank line between the paragraph and the itemize.

Comment: You can use a `\vspace{length}` or `\par` or `\\[length]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just put `\bigskip` after the empty line following `\end{itemize}`

Comment: Putting `\bigskip` did it for me. Thx !

Comment: See this [link](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm)

Comment: @egreg : please make this comment an answer.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\EndItemize\enditemize
\def\enditemize{\EndItemize\bigskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}       
\item item1 ...
\item item2 ....
\end{itemize}                                               

New paragraph etc...... 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would then cause a systematic space after each itemization in the document, right? I don't know if that is what Matthieu is asking...

Answer (score 2):

If you want just a one shot spacing, use `\bigskip` or `\medskip`; for getting symmetric spacing, `enumitem` makes the thing easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{itemize}
\item item1 ...
\item item2 ....
\end{itemize}                                               

\bigskip
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{itemize}[topsep=\bigskipamount]
\item item1 ...
\item item2 ....
\end{itemize}                                               

\lipsum*[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]